# Problem with a div taking the wrong width

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, width, dashboard

so basically I'm working on a Dashboard page project using Next.js (pages router) and tailwind and I made the main Dashboard page component consists of two main divs:
1-the side bar (20% of the width) fixed-positioned with h-full top-0 left-0 overflow-auto
2-the main div for the rest of the content (80% of the width)

the problem is I want to make a header div to be sticky and takes 90% of the width of the main div but instead it takes 90% of the page component itself which means it takes 90% of the viewport and not of the main second div. I tried several solutions but to no avail

here's the code for the Dashboard page component:

```
import React from "react";
import Buttons from "@/DashboardComponents/Buttons";
import { AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";
import DHeader from "../DashboardComponents/DHeader.jsx";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-700 to-slate-800 font-Poppins flex">
      <div className="w-[300px] h-full overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed hidden xl:flex flex-col box-border pt-8 rounded-br-lg rounded-tr-lg bg-[rgb(15,11,33)] items-center pb-6">
        {/* this is the div for the sidebar*/}
        <div className="p-4 border-b-[1px] border-b-white text-lg font-bold tracking-widest ml-2 w-fit h-fit">
          {/* this the title*/}
          <h3 className="text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-white to-slate-500 bg-clip-text">
            Vision UI Free
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div className="pt-10 w-full flex flex-col items-center">
          {/* this is the div for the first buttons */}
          <div className="rounded-lg w-[80%] flex flex-col gap-y-6 box-border py-3 pl-6">
            <Buttons text="Dashboard" icon="home" />
            <Buttons text="Tables" icon="tables" />
            <Buttons text="Billing" icon="billing" />
            <Buttons text="RTL" icon="rtl" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="text-white text-lg font-semibold w-full h-10 flex items-center justify-center">
          {/* this is the div for the next title*/}
          <h3>Account pages</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="rounded-lg w-[80%] flex flex-col gap-y-6 box-border py-3 pl-6">
          {/* this is the div for the second buttons */}
          <Buttons text="Profile" icon="profile" />
          <Buttons text="Sign In" icon="sign in" />
          <Buttons text="Sign Up" icon="sign up" />
        </div>
        <div className="w-[200px] relative h-[200px] mt-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-900 to-fuchsia-600 rounded-xl flex flex-col items-center gap-y-4 pt-12 pb-4">
          {/* this is the div for the gradient picture */}

          <div className="flex items-center justify-center p-2 bg-blue-600 rounded-lg absolute left-3 top-3">
            {/* this is the div for the star */}
            <AiFillStar className="text-white text-xl" />
          </div>
          <div className="text-white pl-4 mt-4">
            {/* this is the div for the center text */}
            <h3>Need help?</h3>
            <p className="text-sm tracking-tightest">Please check our docs</p>
          </div>
          <div className="py-2 px-6 font-semibold bg-black/60 text-white text-sm flex justify-center w-fit mx-auto rounded-lg hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300">
            {/* this is the div for the button */}
            <button>DOCUMENTATION</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=" bg-blue-400 text-white text-center text-sm font-semibold py-[9px] px-10 rounded-xl mt-4 hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300">
          {/* this is the div for the upgrade pro button */}
          <button>Upgrade to PRO</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-48 z-30 bg-red-400 flex flex-col">
        {/* this is the div for the rest of the page*/}
        <DHeader />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

and here is the code of the header component:

```
import React from "react";
import { HiMiniHome } from "react-icons/hi2";
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";
import { RiSettings4Fill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { BsFillBellFill } from "react-icons/bs";

const DHeader = () => {
  return (
    <header className="sticky top-4 w-[90%] mx-auto border-[1px] border-white h-[85px] bg-transparent flex justify-between items-center">
      {/* this is the div for the actual header container */}
      <div>
        {/* this is the div for the most left container */}
        <div>
          <div className=" text-gray-600 text-sm">
            {/* this is the div for the home icon */}
            <HiMiniHome />
          </div>
          <span> / Dashboard</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* this is the div for the most right container */}
        asdfjkdjfjfskdfjj
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default DHeader;
```